# How do I find out which registries that I am already logged into?

Tags: docker

I have logged into multiple registries over the course of few days but dont exactly remember after a few days. Is there a command which tells me which repository i am logged into? for example, I logged into

redhat.registory.io
dockerhub.com
privaterepoxxx

I tried 'docker info' but it is lists only the dockerhub registry. 
the ~/.docker/config gives me this information but I need to know if there is a way to find this information via issuing a command

Comment: Not that I know of, why do you need to know?

Answer (score 3):

To extract a list of logged in servers from the `config.json` using `jq`, you can use the following:

```
jq -r '.auths | keys[]' ~/.docker/config.json
```